# creating a pdf in R that is vertically justified

Tags: pdf, r

Question:  how can you create a pdf where the output is vertically
justified, with for example, a one inch margin on top using `pdf()`.

For example in

```
pdf(file='test.pdf', paper='letter', pagecentre=F)
### code for plot here ###
dev.off()
```

is there an option where it generate output that starts from the top of the
page rather than printing from the bottom of the page (which is what happens when `pagecentre=F`).  Or will this require
some adjustment of settings in `par()`?

Answer (score 1):

I always use

```
pdf(file="/tmp/foo.pdf", width=10.5, height=8)
plot(....)
dev.off()
```

which nicely fills the page with just 1/2 inch spacing.  You can flip width and height arguments to go to 'portrait' rather than 'landscape'.

Comment: Thanks.  However, suppose you're interested in just filling the top half of the page with the figure that's 4 x 4"?  I wish there was a vertical justify option, besides just the pagecentre parameter.

Comment: Use par(mfrow=c(2,2)) and put an empty plot below --- but R is *not* a typesetting system.  Use e.g. Sweave for that.